# How to test POST request parameters an Express app using supertest?

Tags: node.js, http, testing, express, supertest

I'm creating an API using Express 4.0.0 and one of the routes takes a POST. Currently I'm just trying to have it echo a name sent in the request parameters. The response is a JSON object, but the request expects form fields.

```
users.post '/user', (req, res) ->
    res.json name: req.params.name
```

My test sets the `type()` to `form` which should allow `send()` to pass the hash as POST parameters/fields.

```
describe 'POST /user', ->
    it 'should echo the name sent', (done) ->
        request app
        .post '/user'
        .type 'form'
        .send name: 'Foo'
        .expect '{"name":"Foo"}'
        .end done
```

Regardless, my test fails and in Express, my `req.params` is empty, `req.param('name')` comes up `undefined` and `req.body` is also empty.

Is there some `req.fields` attribute I'm not aware of, or is my test flawed somehow?

Comment: Are you using express body parser?

Comment: No, I'm not using it.

Comment: What version of express you have?

Comment: Express 4.0.0, I've updated the question with this detail as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: You need to parse the body to get that, you can do `app.use(require('body-parser')())` and then change your code with `name: req.param('name')`.

So express(and actually node.js http server) will call the request call whenever a http request header have been received and not the body of the request. You have to explicitly read  and wait for the body to come and parse it yourself.

Luckily there are express middleware modules that parses the body for you. In this case you are sending a urlencoded/form body, so you need to parse it as such. Use any of these modules according to their examples:

- [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)
- [body](https://github.com/raynos/body)

Assuming you use `body-parser`, then if you want it to parse the body for all routes then just do `app.use(require('body-parser')()`. If you want it to parse the body for a particular route then do this:

```
bodyParser = require('body-parser')()
app.post '/user', bodyParser, (req, res) ->
    res.json name: req.param('name')
```

Once you got the body parsing right, then you can access it either through `req.body`(for example `req.body.name`) property or [`req.param`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.param) function(for example `req.param('name')`). The latter will also search through query string and url parameters.

Note that if you want to parse a body with attached files(for uploading files) you need a multipart parser and not just a urlencoded one:

- [connect-multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty)
- [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy)